# C++ Time adding + over time detection

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

Currently working on an assignment for a C++ class I'm taking. The goal of the project is to show military time accurately. Hours can range from 0-23 and minutes 0-59.

For the first part, I created a constructor that accepts a hour parameter and a optional minute parameter.

Here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

// Class Time
class time
{
private:
    int hours, minutes;
public:
    time(int, int = 0);
    void displayTime();
    void setTime(int);
};

// Max time possibilities
const int MAXMIN = 59;
const int MAXHOUR = 23;

// time constructor
time::time(int conHour, int conMin)
{
// Check for max hour limitations
if (conHour > MAXHOUR)
{
    hours = MAXHOUR;
}
else
{
    hours = conHour;
}

// Check for max minute limitation
if (conMin > MAXMIN)
{
    minutes = MAXMIN;
}
else
{
    minutes = conMin;
}
}
```

If the we place in anything higher than 23 for the hours or 59 for the minutes, it just sets them to the maximums 23, 59 respectively.

The next step was to add a "setTime" function where the user/sys can add minutes to the time (This is where the issue lies). If the minutes added would cause the minutes to go above 59, we add one to the hour. If the hour add causes the hours to go above 23, we reset it back to 0 and count up as needed.

currently I have the function:

```
// Set the time
void time::setTime(int newMin)
{
    int addMin = newMin;

// Check for max minutes, if so add an hour
do
{
    if (minutes + (addMin - MAXMIN) > MAXMIN)
    {
        addMin - MAXMIN;
        if (hours + 1 > MAXHOUR)
        {
            hours = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            hours = hours + 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        minutes += addMin;
    }

} while (minutes + addMin > MAXMIN);

minutes += addMin;
```

I wrote the function where the loop would continuously check if the addMin amount would cause the minute to go above 59. The way I'm fairly sure I wrote it was to check if the minutes +(addMin-MAXMIN) is greater than the MAXMIN, if it is, subtract 59 and then add an hour. That is where the hour check comes in and checks if the hour would go above 23, if so reset it. The idea is that it would keep looping through until we have a set time. However, when running the program, it stalls out. This leads me to believe I have an infinite loop somewhere, but I cannot identify it.

Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{   
    time aTime(50,15);
aTime.displayTime();

aTime.setTime(100);
aTime.displayTime();
// Pause before we exit
system("pause.exe");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `addMin - MAXMIN;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Would I have to strictly define -59? I thought it would be able to see the constant declaration, unless my scope is off

Comment: Oh.. wait. I see now, I needed to add 'addMin = addMin - MAXMIN'. I understand now, silly mistake on my part

Comment: Off topic: `setTime` is a misnomer. It doesn't set time. It increments time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line `addMin - MAXMIN` did not do anything as I hadn't included `addMIN = addMin - MAXMIN` the variable was not getting updated on each iteration.

Credits to @immibis